# How to specify font style path in PIL.ImageFont.truetype(), while coding in google colab?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

```
text=data1 
img = PIL.Image.new('RGBA',(1000,1500),'white')
draw = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = PIL.ImageFont.truetype('Arial.ttf', 16)
draw.text((0, 0), text, fill="black",font=font)
img.save(f"{name1}_{class1}.png")
```

While coding in Google colab, I don't know how to specify path in font style,here

```
 font = PIL.ImageFont.truetype('Arial.ttf', 16)
```

It gives me error,

> can not open resource

I use Samsung galaxy tab a to code in google colab.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Google Colab which is based on Linux operating system so the font you are accessing which is in case Arial not exists all you need to do is to download the font and copy it in this directory "/usr/share/fonts/truetype" with folder name as shown in the picture that's how you can access the font.

[image: Refrence]

Comment: What if we'd like to pick a font likely to "just work" on any OS? Any suggestions?